# Am I using flex-box correctly and the most optimal way?

Tags: css, flexbox

The code snippet below technically achieves the goal of having div tables dynamically resize and stack when the screen becomes to narrow (for mobile).

My question, am I using flex box correctly? Or am I wasting code and complicating certain areas which may cause unneeded errors? My CSS feels verbose with all of the flex displays for sub div's.

Also, I'm just getting into style coding and am not too familiar with which styles are inherited.  Making my code longer than it probably needs to be.

Thanks,

```css
#container,
#container-1-2,
#container-3-4 {
  display: flex;
}

.ctable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  height: 350px;
}

.ctable-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 10%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 138%;
  width: 100%;
}

.ctable-header2 {
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 5%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 188%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.ctable-header2>div {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fine-prt {
  font-size: 40%;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 100%;
}

.ctable-list {
  flex-basis: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 5;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
}

.ctable-list div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.ctable-list div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #container-3-4,
  #container-1-2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-1-2">
    <div class="ctable">
      <div class="ctable-header">Header 1</div>
      <div class="ctable-header2"><sup>$</sup>PRICE
        <div class="fine-prt">fine print</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ctable-list">
        <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
        <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        <div>list feature C - example ccccccc</div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ctable">
      <div class="ctable-header">Header 2</div>
      <div class="ctable-header2"><sup>$</sup>PRICE
        <div class="fine-prt">fine print</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ctable-list">
        <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
        <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
        <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
        <div>list feature D - example dddddddd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container-3-4">
    <div class="ctable">
      <div class="ctable-header">Header 3</div>
      <div class="ctable-header2"><sup>$</sup>PRICE
        <div class="fine-prt">fine print</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ctable-list">
        <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
        <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
        <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
        <div>list feature D - example dddddddd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ctable">
      <div class="ctable-header">Header 4</div>
      <div class="ctable-header2"><sup>$</sup>PRICE
        <div class="fine-prt">fine print</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ctable-list">
        <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
        <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
        <div>list feature c - example ccccccc</div>
        <div>list feature D - example dddddddd dddddddddddd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or undesired behaviors?

Comment: I do think you are complicating things a bit; from what I can see, the classes where you set `flex-direction: column` where you have a list divs inside are not necessary, since divs are block elements and will stack regardless; I'll see if I can simplify the code a little bit

Answer (score 0):

This might need more styling to accommodate some of your behaviors, but its the basic idea that I have, let me know if this points you in a good direction and if so maybe we can improve upon it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  flex-basis: 23%;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
}

.card header {
  text-align: center;
}

.card header small {
  display: block;
}

.card .body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
}

.card .body>div {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.card .body>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  .card:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .card:nth-child(3) {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <header>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <sup>$</sup><span>PRICE</span>
      <small>fine print</small>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
      <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
      <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
      <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <header>
      <h2>Ver Very Very Very Large Header</h2>
      <sup>$</sup><span>PRICE</span>
      <small>fine print</small>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
      <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
      <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
      <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
      <div>list feature D - example dddddddd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <header>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <sup>$</sup><span>PRICE</span>
      <small>fine print</small>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
      <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
      <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
      <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
      <div>list feature D - example dddddddd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <header>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <sup>$</sup><span>PRICE</span>
      <small>fine print</small>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
      <div>list feature a - example aaaaa</div>
      <div>list feature b - example bbbbbbbb</div>
      <div>list feature C - example ccccccc cccccccccc</div>
      <div>list feature D - example dddddddd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the basic idea.  I forgot to add, when one of the headers is 2 lines either with a <br> or too long so it wraps, I still wanted to keep all of the cards elements aligned with each other.  Guess I should've added a 2 line header in my example.

Comment: I added a larger header maybe to see if that's kinda what you need, or you mean that even when it has two lines then the header itself stays the same size as the others? let me know;

Comment: even when it has 2 lines then the header itself stays the same as the others

Comment: I think a fixed height for the header would be enough and work pretty well; of course a few things to consider would be what to do if header runs out of space; either making some of the content hide or reduce its size

Comment: I'm trying to keep things responsive for mobile and tablet viewing.  Does having fixed heights mess that up or am I thinking about this wrong?  Also,  The "body" in mine evenly spaces the div elements.  Is this only accomplished with flex-box in the body?

Comment: Okay so, first, regarding `height` shouldn't give you problems for mobile and tablet, as in those screens the optimal view is vertical, so fixed height will not really break anything.... Regarding the body of the card yeah I noticed that now, in that case I think what you had works really well, setting the body as a flex container and make the items inside fill the space, so you should stick with that with few CSS rules as well